# Is there a way to make my Rock, Paper, Scissors game more concise?

Tags: javascript, beginner, game, rock-paper-scissors

I am learning JavaScript and I just wrote a Rock, Paper, Scissors game that will first prompt the two players for their choices and validate them. In the event of a tie, each player will choose their answer again and it will once again be validated. Everything works fine, but it feels like I have a lot of repetition going on here. Since I'm new to this, I can't figure out a way to make this more concise if possible.

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    while (choice1 != 'rock' && choice1 != 'paper' && choice1 != "scissors"){
        choice1 = prompt('Invalid entry. Player 1, please choose rock, paper, or scissors only');
    }    
    while (choice2 != 'rock' && choice2 != 'paper' && choice2 != "scissors"){
        choice2 = prompt('Invalid entry. Player 2, please choose rock, paper, or scissors only');
    }
    while (choice1 == choice2){
        choice1 = prompt('Tiebreaker!. Player 1, please choose rock, paper, or scissors only');
     while (choice1 != 'rock' && choice1 != 'paper' && choice1 != "scissors"){
        choice1 = prompt('Invalid Entry. Player 1, please choose rock, paper, or scissors only');
        }
        choice2 = prompt('Tiebreaker!. Player 2, please choose rock, paper, or scissors only');
     while (choice2 != 'rock' && choice2 != 'paper' && choice2 != "scissors"){
        choice2 = prompt('Invalid Entry. Player 2, please choose rock, paper, or scissors only');
        }

    }
    if (choice1 == 'rock'){
        if (choice2 == 'scissors'){
            return 'rock wins';
        }
        else{
            return 'paper wins';
        }
    }
    if (choice1 == 'paper'){
        if (choice2 == 'rock'){
            return 'paper wins';
        }
        else{
            return 'scissors wins';
        }
    }  
    if (choice1 == 'scissors' ){
        if (choice2 == 'rock'){
            return 'rock wins';
        }
        else{
            return 'scissors wins';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just build an object with the associativity.

```
// what wins to what
var winsTo = {
  'rock': 'scissors',
  'paper': 'rock',
  'scissors': 'paper',
};

// invalid selected
if (!(choice1 in winsTo && choice2 in winsTo)) {
  alert("bad choice !");
  return;
}

// same choice => equality
if (choice1 == choice2) {
  alert("Equality!");
} else if (winsTo[choice1] == choice2) {
  alert("choice1 won!");
} else {
  alert("choice2 won!");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While you can get away with this sort of thing in rock paper scissors, any more options and it becomes unmanageable. (For example, rock paper scissors lizard spock).

There is a general-case solution to this problem and it is called an *adjacency matrix*.
An adjacency matrix is basically the computer's representation of a directed graph.
This is useful because your problem actually has a directed graph under the hood.

Consider the following graph:

[image: Rock Paper Scissors state machine]
    . . .

In this situation, we begin at the starting state, then follow the transitions for each player's move (not all transitions are shown).

Now it is a mathematical property of state machines such as this that they can be represented using a matrix (which we call an `Array` in computer science).

So we create an array with a row and column for each state (1 represents victory for player 1, 0 represents tie, -1 represents victory for player 2)

```
Player 2 ->  Rock    Paper    Scissors
Player 1:
Rock          0        1         1
Paper         1        0         -1
Scissors      -1       1         0
```

Now if we get the user's input as a number where rock is assigned the value of `0`, paper the value `1` and scissors `2`, we can look up the result of our operation using:

```
var result = adjacency_matrix[player_1_value][player_2_value];

switch( result )
{
    case 0:
        break;
        // Tie
    case 1:
        // Victory player 1
        break;

    case 2:
        // Victory player 2
        break;
}
```

Now there are some nice things that are Javascript specific like dictionaries which make this a little nicer to read in code, but if you understand the fundamentals of this solution you will be able to solve any of this type of problem in any language.

Comment: That certainly works, but you don't need that 2nd depth in this case. Let's do it simply!

Comment: Actually there is no second depth. If you look again at the diagram you will notice that each state in the "second depth" has only one transition to a final state. I included it for the sake of generality.

Comment: I mean in the javascript code, actually